# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFBoolean stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:]

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, twilio

I am using `PhoneKit` with `TwilioSDK` in my `Objective-C` project. I am using `AFNetworking` to fetch the token string. I am correctly getting the token string but it crashes while executing this line: `[PKTPhone sharedPhone].capabilityToken = tokenString;` With the following error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFBoolean
>   stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:]

This is my code:

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
[manager GET:SERVER_URL parameters:@{@"clientName": @"DEMO"}
progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull downloadProgress){
    NSLog(@"progress: %@", downloadProgress);
} success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
    NSString *tokenString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [responseObject valueForKey:@"token"]];
    [PKTPhone sharedPhone].capabilityToken = tokenString;
} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
     NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
}];
```

Comment: What type is `tokenString`?  You seem to assume it's a string, but it's coming up as an `NSNumber`.

Comment: I have checked it. It is NSString

Comment: Are you sure as to which line is crashing?  With the given code, there's no way `tokenString` is anything but a string, but the crash is being caused by passing an `NSNumber` to something expecting a string.

Comment: This is my server response: responseObject
{
    clients =     (
        DEMO,
        default
    );
    token = "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzY29wZSI6InNjb3BlOmNsaWVudDppbmNvbWluZz9jbGllbnROYW1lPU51aXNhbmNlIHNjb3BlOmNsaWVudDpvdXRnb2luZz9hcHBTaWQ9MCZhcHBQYXJhbXM9JmNsaWVudE5hbWU9TnVpc2FuY2UiLCJpc3MiOmZhbHNlLCJleHAiOjE0NjIzNDc5Njl9.9WehbhjPC5--fhBOfNEskPJxNW8OMNnD0xq18_zz0Yw";
}

Comment: when i remove the dot (.) between the two 9's (5Njl9.9Weh) as you can see in the token string above. Then it works fine. I wonder whats the problem with the (.)

Comment: Are you sure the crash isn't inside the Twilio library?  Please add the full stack trace from the crash.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110961/discussion-between-hamid-and-avi).